# Which way is better to call a jquery function twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a javascript jquery function which I need to use twice, in 2 different files.

Now, the question is, which is the better way to implement it, performance-wise. Should I declare function global using 'window' variable, or should I declare the function in each of the files?

Please keep in mind that traffic is not an issue, the script will be used from the hard-drive.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show us what you have?

Comment: Performancewise the difference is in all practical purposes zero. That's not what you should be concentrating on.

Comment: @alejandro-bar sorry, I cannot do that

Comment: @Juhana thank you for your help, I got it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer follows the DRY Principle (Don't Repeat Yourself). If you put the function in both files, and later find a bug on Page #1, someone has to remember that the function is duplicated on Page #2 as well (in this case, assume the bug report says "Page #1 doesn't work properly"). From that bug report, would the developer know to also modify Page #2? To avoid the human error piece, I'd always recommend you don't copy/paste functions into multiple locations.

Performance wise, if you're not concerned about traffic, the difference is nanoseconds slower wrapping it in a shared function as you do have to create an additional stack frame for the shared function call that in turn calls jQuery, but we're really talking nanoseconds. For a few nanoseconds lost, I'd say DRY is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the detail I needed to know.

Comment: You could always mark it as the answer then so others can find it ;)